# ClusterManager performance - Prevent unclustering of out of bounds clusters

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a HUGE list of markers to display on my map fragment. I implemented a ClusterManager to increase performance and it works well other than a certain situation: When the user zooms in, the clusters on screen uncluster to reveal the markers (with no performance issues), but when the user zooms out (due to the density of markers) a large number of off-screen markers have been unclustered and despite clustering as the user zooms out there is performance issues.

Is there anyway to combat such a situation?

I tried to implement a Viewport Marker Management work around (below), where onCameraChange the ClusterItems are cleared from the ClusterManager then add the ClusterItems which are within the latLngBound given by the visible region. This made performance worse.

```
    private void setUpClusterer() {

    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Crag>(this, mainGoogleMap){
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            super.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
            LatLngBounds bounds = mainGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

            mClusterManager.clearItems();

            for(Crag c : crags){
                if (bounds.contains(c.getPosition())){
                    mClusterManager.addItem(c);
                }
            }

        }
    };


    mainGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    mainGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same problem with around 10k Cluster Items in small area. I was wondering if You have found a solution for this problem and are willing to share that.

Comment: @KasparTr I've a similar issue, do you have solved?

Comment: @CeccoCQ not technically. I 'solved' it from a business perspective by filtering markers by default and letting the user choose to display more/less at will. When filtering use primitive Sets for increased performance. What I did was composed a list of filtered ClusterItems. Then only use the Clustermanager by doing .clear() and  .add() (bulk add the list). Other then that I suggest to use sqlLight and fetch only the markers from the db which are withing the LatLngBounds.